# Run Time Error 3464: Data Type Mismatch in criteria. Need to export access reports as PDFs

Tags: vba, ms-access

I realise this is probably the simplest question ever but I'm about to tear my hair out.

I am trying to export an access report for a single record in my data table, as specific by the field Unique ID.

I keep getting thrown a run time error occurring in the `DoCmd.OpenReport` line. For the life of me I cannot figure out where or why this is happening.

In a perfect world, I would want the user to be able to enter as many Unique ID's as they want, and it would export a single report for each line (not a large report containing all rows).

```
Sub test()
   Dim MyFileName       As String
   Dim rst              As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strReportName    As String       ' report name to work with
   Dim strOutPutFile    As String       ' pdf output file on disk
        
   strReportName = "TEST"
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table")
  
   Do While rst.EOF = False          
      strOutPutFile = "C:\Users\me\Documents" & "-test1-" & rst![Unique ID] & ".pdf"  ' output file = ID.pdf
      DoCmd.OpenReport "TEST", acViewPreview , , "Unique ID = " & rst![Unique ID]
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strOutPutFile
      DoCmd.Close acReport, strReportName
     
      rst.MoveNext         
   Loop
  
   rst.Close
  
   MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: `"Unique ID = " & Unique ID` Should `& Unique ID` be `& rst![Unique ID]`? A variable cannot have spaces in it's name so `Unique ID` after the `&` will give you a compile error.

Comment: Try `DoCmd.OpenReport "TEST", acViewPreview , , "[Unique ID] = " & rst![Unique ID]` - you are not telling the code what UniqueID is otherwise

Comment: When I change it to rst![Unique ID] I now get a Run Time Error 3464: Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression. I don't fully understand Access reports as in the template I did rename the 'label' of the field to "Project ID". Unsure if this makes a difference

Comment: Is `Unique ID` a numeric datatype? If it is text, then try `DoCmd.OpenReport "TEST", acViewPreview , , "[Unique ID] = '" & Unique ID & "'"`, i.e. wrapping the concatenated value in single quotes.

Comment: It is meant to be (i.e. only numbers are present in the field), but where I get this data from can be a bit messy so I'm actually thinking it might be a varchar field? Using that got me one step - it exports a seperate report for each line (woo), but it looped through every line in the database without letting me input a unique ID to choose which ones I want. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: And why would you expect it to stop and allow input? Reference to recordset field is the input to filter report. If you want to limit records to output, then the recordset must have filter criteria, such as: `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Unique ID] FROM table WHERE <some criteria here>"`. Your question is too broad. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Do you really have a table named "table"?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with VBA and that is what the example code I used was doing? It would allow me to put input a ID, and it would export the PDF report for the corresponding line in the data. I'm confused as to what you mean? I don't want to hardcode anything as the reports needed each day will vary based on the new rows entered into the data table.
Also no, but I can't publish the name of my data table so I used an alias.

Comment: Review the link I referenced. I don't know what example code you followed but the code you posted will not prompt and wait for anything. You have solution to the error, now your 'want to' is another topic and is too broad to be answered here. Review the tutorial in the link and make a code attempt and when you have specific issue, post a question.

Comment: The link shows how to dynamically build filter criteria. In your case, you would want to concatenate criteria to the SQL statement: `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Unique ID] FROM table WHERE " & strCriteria & ")"`. How you build value for strCriteria variable is what you need to develop.